# Setting the width of textLabel in a UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios, ios4

I have a UITableViewCell that has a textLabel and a UITextField attached as a subview like this:

```
cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:Value1CellIdentifier];
cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:Value1CellIdentifier] autorelease];
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
cell.textLabel.text = @"Name";
UITextField *playerTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(110, 10, 185, 30)];
playerTextField.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
playerTextField.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
playerTextField.placeholder = @"John Doe";
playerTextField.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
[playerTextField setEnabled: YES];
[cell addSubview:playerTextField];
[playerTextField release];
```

The textLabel takes up way to much space. How can I set the width of the textLabel, so that the rest of the UITableViewCell gets the reminding width?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

textLabel is read-only. Why not create your own and add that to the cell?

Comment: Well actually i can just set the position of my added subview to a more "left" one, and it works :)

Answer (score 1):

In short, you could set the width of the UITextLabel inside a UITableViewCell using the layoutSubviews method, which is executed in the UITableViewCell class. Using it would require you to most likely create your own custom UITableViewCell class like [Joseph Tura](https://stackoverflow.com/users/406652/joseph-tura) mentioned.

A posted answer in the following link has a great example on how to use layoutSubviews:
[Having a UITextField in a UITableViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409259/having-a-uitextfield-in-a-uitableviewcell)

This solution outlines an alternate approach as well:
[How to put a UITextField inside of a UITableViewCell (grouped)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487413/how-to-put-a-uitextfield-inside-of-a-uitableviewcell-grouped)