# How would I go about creating a Text Field in a UITableView

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uitextfield

I need to programatically add a text field input into a table view cell. How could I do this in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set it as one of the views within the row - for example, as the accessory view:

```
UITextField* input = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5,5,80,20)];
[input setDelegate:self];
[cell setAccessoryView:input];
[input release];
```

Then you SHOULD be able to access the value with [(UITextField*)[[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] accessoryView] text];  Make sure you set up that delegate info on whichever object you make the delegate.

Comment: You could also add it as a new subview within the cell, but if you're doing that it's best to create your own subclass of UITableViewCell; that way you can use Interface Builder to set it up as well.

Comment: When I set it as the delegate, It says that self isnt an appropriate delegate. Is there somehting I need to add?

Comment: @laxj11 When setting up the delegate, in the main class's .h file you should make it look like so:

`@interface YourClassNameHere : UITableViewController<UITextFieldDelegate> {`

Answer (score 2):

I've found this tutorial really helpful for creating xib (nib) based table cells. Then you can add whatever you like in each cell row.

http://clingingtoideas.blogspot.com/2011/03/uitableview-how-to-part-5-more-about.html

Answer (score 1):

This has been answered before ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487413/how-to-put-a-uitextfield-inside-of-a-uitableviewcell-grouped), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4568214/uitextfield-in-uitableviewcell-help)), but the best place to start in my opinion is the [Table View Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW18), where you can find three different methods regarding cell customization.

Comment: Yeah, I figured but I serched around for a while and couldnt find anything helpful :)