# Adding cells dynamically to UItableview when Button clicks

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have 2 UITextField's and a button when i click on button  after filling those  i have to get UItextfields and buttons in tableview cell with same format when i fill these and click the button have to add same textfields to next cell keeping the above cell as same and also the data in textfields showld not be removed

Iam new to this programming i dont know how to add view to cell when ever button clicks
Help me out from this.

```
 -(IBAction)btnaddbusiness:(UIButton*)sender
{
    tableView=[[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 370, 300, 30)];

    tableView.delegate=self;
    tableView.dataSource=self;
    [testscroll addSubview:tableView];
        i=i+1;
    if(sender.tag==1 || i==1)
    {

        if([txtprovEmail1.text isEqualToString:@""] && [txtprovName1.text isEqualToString:@""])
        {

        }
        else
        {
            testscroll.contentSize=CGSizeMake(320, 500);
            view1=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 30)];

            txtprovName2 =[[UITextField alloc]init];
            [txtprovName2 setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,116, 30)];
            [txtprovName2 setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];
            [txtprovName2 setAutocorrectionType:UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo];
            txtprovName2.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentCenter;
            txtprovName2.placeholder=@"Provider Name";
            txtprovName2.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"System" size:11];
            txtprovName2.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
            [view1 addSubview:txtprovName2];

            txtprovEmail2 =[[UITextField alloc]init];
            [txtprovEmail2 setFrame:CGRectMake(130, 0,116, 30)];
            [txtprovEmail2 setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];
            [txtprovEmail2 setAutocorrectionType:UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo];
            txtprovEmail2.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentCenter;
            txtprovEmail2.placeholder=@"Provider Email";
            txtprovEmail2.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"System" size:11];
            txtprovEmail2.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
            [view1 addSubview:txtprovEmail2];

            btnRemove1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
            btnRemove1.frame = CGRectMake(268, 0,80, 30);
            [btnRemove1 setTitle:@"Remove" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [btnRemove1.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:14]];
            // [ btnRemove1 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background-button.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            btnRemove1.titleLabel.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
            btnRemove1.tag=1;

           // [btnRemove1 addTarget:self action:@selector(btnRemove1Clicked)                forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
           [ view1 addSubview: btnRemove1];

          /*  btnsubmit = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
            btnsubmit.frame = CGRectMake(40, 470,80, 30);
            [btnsubmit setTitle:@"Submit" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [btnsubmit.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:14]];

            btnsubmit.titleLabel.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];

            [btnsubmit addTarget:self
                          action:@selector(btnsubmitclicked)
                forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [ testscroll addSubview: btnsubmit];*/



          /*
            btnreset = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
            btnreset.frame = CGRectMake(100, 470,80, 30);
            [btnreset setTitle:@"Reset" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [btnreset.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:14]];

            btnreset.titleLabel.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];

            [btnreset addTarget:self
                         action:@selector(btnResetclicked)
               forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [ testscroll addSubview: btnreset];




            */



            sender.tag=2;

        }
    }

    else if(sender.tag==2|| i==2)
    {

        if(txtprovEmail2.text==NULL && txtprovName2.text==NULL)
        {

        }
        else
        {

            testscroll.contentSize=CGSizeMake(320, 600);
            testscroll.pagingEnabled=YES;
            view2=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 30)];
            txtprovName3 =[[UITextField alloc]init];
            [txtprovName3 setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 470,94, 30)];
            [txtprovName3 setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];
            [txtprovName3 setAutocorrectionType:UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo];
            txtprovName3.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentCenter;
            txtprovName3.placeholder=@"Provider Name";
            txtprovName3.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"System" size:11];
            txtprovName3.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
            [view2 addSubview:txtprovName3];

            txtprovEmail3 =[[UITextField alloc]init];
            [txtprovEmail3 setFrame:CGRectMake(118, 470,92, 30)];
            [txtprovEmail3 setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];
            [txtprovEmail3 setAutocorrectionType:UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo];
            txtprovEmail3.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentCenter;
            txtprovEmail3.placeholder=@"Provider Email";
            txtprovEmail3.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"System" size:11];
            txtprovEmail3.userInteractionEnabled=YES;

            [view2 addSubview:txtprovEmail3];

            btnRemove2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
            btnRemove2.frame=CGRectMake(210, 470, 80, 30) ;
            [btnRemove2 setTitle:@"Remove" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [btnRemove2.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:14]];
            // [ btnRemove1 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background-button.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            btnRemove2.titleLabel.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];

           /* [btnRemove2 addTarget:self    action:@selector(btnRemove2Clicked)
                 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];*/
            btnRemove2.tag=2;
            [view2 addSubview:btnRemove2];

            [btnreset removeFromSuperview];
            [btnsubmit removeFromSuperview];


            [ btnsubmit setFrame:CGRectMake(80, 510, 50, 30)];
            [btnreset setFrame:CGRectMake(80, 510, 50, 30)];

            sender.tag=3;

        }
    }

    else if(sender.tag==3 || i==3)
    {

        if(txtprovEmail3.text==NULL && txtprovName3.text==NULL)
        {

        }
        else
        {

            testscroll.contentSize=CGSizeMake(320, 700);

            txtprovName4 =[[UITextField alloc]init];
            [txtprovName4 setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 510,94, 30)];
            [txtprovName4 setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];
            [txtprovName4 setAutocorrectionType:UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo];
            txtprovName4.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentCenter;
            txtprovName4.placeholder=@"Provider Name";
            txtprovName4.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"System" size:11];
            txtprovName4.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
            [testscroll addSubview:txtprovName4];

            txtprovEmail4 =[[UITextField alloc]init];
            [txtprovEmail4 setFrame:CGRectMake(118, 510,92, 30)];
            [txtprovEmail4 setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];
            [txtprovEmail4 setAutocorrectionType:UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo];
            txtprovEmail4.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentCenter;
            txtprovEmail4.placeholder=@"Provider Email";
            txtprovEmail4.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"System" size:11];
            txtprovEmail4.userInteractionEnabled=YES;

            [testscroll addSubview:txtprovEmail4];

            btnRemove3 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
            btnRemove3.frame = CGRectMake(210, 510,80, 30);
            [btnRemove3 setTitle:@"Remove" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [btnRemove3.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:14]];
            // [ btnRemove1 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background-button.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            btnRemove3.titleLabel.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];

            [btnRemove3 addTarget:self    action:@selector(btnRemove3Clicked)
                 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            btnRemove3.tag=3;
            [testscroll addSubview:btnRemove3];

            [btnreset removeFromSuperview];
            [btnsubmit removeFromSuperview];

            [ btnsubmit setFrame:CGRectMake(40, 550, 50, 30)];
            [btnreset setFrame:CGRectMake(100, 550, 50, 30)];
            sender.tag=4;

        }
    }
    else if(sender.tag==4||i==4)
    {

        if(txtprovEmail4.text==NULL && txtprovName4.text==NULL)
        {

        }
        else
        { testscroll.contentSize=CGSizeMake(320, 800);
            txtprovName5 =[[UITextField alloc]init];
            [txtprovName5 setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 550,94, 30)];
            [txtprovName5 setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];
            [txtprovName5 setAutocorrectionType:UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo];
            txtprovName5.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentCenter;
            txtprovName5.placeholder=@"Provider Name";
            txtprovName5.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"System" size:11];
            txtprovName5.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
            [testscroll addSubview:txtprovName5];

            txtprovEmail5 =[[UITextField alloc]init];
            [txtprovEmail5 setFrame:CGRectMake(118, 550,92, 30)];
            [txtprovEmail5 setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];
            [txtprovEmail5 setAutocorrectionType:UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo];
            txtprovEmail5.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentCenter;
            txtprovEmail5.placeholder=@"Provider Email";
            txtprovEmail5.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"System" size:11];
            txtprovEmail5.userInteractionEnabled=YES;

            [testscroll addSubview:txtprovEmail5];

            btnRemove4 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
            btnRemove4.frame = CGRectMake(210, 550,80, 30);
            [btnRemove4 setTitle:@"Remove" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [btnRemove4.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:14]];
            // [ btnRemove1 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background-button.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            btnRemove4.titleLabel.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];

            [btnRemove4 addTarget:self    action:@selector(btnRemove4Clicked)
                 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            btnRemove4.tag=4;
            [testscroll addSubview:btnRemove4];
            testscroll.scrollEnabled=YES;


            [btnreset removeFromSuperview];
            [btnsubmit removeFromSuperview];

            [ btnsubmit setFrame:CGRectMake(40, 690, 50, 30)];
            [btnreset setFrame:CGRectMake(100, 690, 50, 30)];



        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try searching on custom uitableviewcell https://www.google.co.in/search?q=custom+table+view+ios&aq=2&oq=custom+tab&aqs=chrome.3.57j0l3j60l2.6698&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=custom+uitableviewcell+uitextfield&oq=custom+uitableviewcell+uitextfield&gs_l=serp.1.0.0.7155.11239.3.12222.11.6.1.4.4.0.118.577.4j2.6.0.les%3B..0.0...1c.1.5.psy-ab.KFxGmYGQ-84&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.43287494,d.bmk&fp=1fc7e9b832ceaa6b&biw=982&bih=581

Comment: when addbutton is clicked i want to add another view to tableviewcell like that how can i add cells dynamically using tags

Comment: you can add your view and keep it hidden in beginning and when button is clicked reload your table and according to condition set hidden to false.

Comment: see my edit in question .i want to add those functionality to table view how can i

Answer (score 0):

You can download sample app from [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/UICatalog/Introduction/Intro.html)

Following links will also help you.

[UITextField in UITableViewCell Help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4568214/uitextfield-in-uitableviewcell-help)

[How to put a UITextField inside of a UITableViewCell (grouped)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487413/how-to-put-a-uitextfield-inside-of-a-uitableviewcell-grouped)

**EDIT:**

You only need to **reload** (`[tablename reloadData];`) your table in  `-(IBAction)btnaddbusiness:(UIButton*)sender`.

Adding views that you are doing should be in  `rowForIndexPath:`.

What you can do is in your function set one variable **boolean** to **TRUE** and **reload** your table , and in `rowForIndexPath`, check if that variable is **true** then set **hidden** property of ur view to **False** and vice-versa.

Comment: how can i add it for various rows in cell for row at indexpath

Comment: you can create **txtprovName2** in **rowForIndexPath** and add this to your row like `[cell.contentView addSubview: txtprovName2];`